# Incrementar el tamaño de una animación en HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, animación

Estoy intentando aumentar el tamaño de toda la animación de un check hecho en css, pero son tantas areas que hay que modificar que me pierdo, no soy un experto con css, si alguien pudiera ayudarme, aquí el código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
check
</title>
<style type=text/css>
.check_mark {
  width: 80px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}

.sa-icon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success {
  border-color: #4CAF50;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success::before, .sa-icon.sa-success::after {
  content: '';
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.sa-icon.sa-success::before {
  -webkit-border-radius: 120px 0 0 120px;
  border-radius: 120px 0 0 120px;
  top: -7px;
  left: -33px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 60px 60px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success::after {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 120px 120px 0;
  border-radius: 0 120px 120px 0;
  top: -11px;
  left: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 60px;
  transform-origin: 0px 60px;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-placeholder {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid rgba(76, 175, 80, .5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: -4px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-fix {
  width: 5px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 28px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.sa-icon.sa-success.animate::after {
  -webkit-animation: rotatePlaceholder 4.25s ease-in;
  animation: rotatePlaceholder 4.25s ease-in;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success {
  border-color: transparent\9;
}
.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line.sa-tip {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) \9;
}
.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line.sa-long {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) \9;
}

.animateSuccessTip {
  -webkit-animation: animateSuccessTip 0.75s;
  animation: animateSuccessTip 0.75s;
}

.animateSuccessLong {
  -webkit-animation: animateSuccessLong 0.75s;
  animation: animateSuccessLong 0.75s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateSuccessLong {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    right: 46px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  65% {
    width: 0;
    right: 46px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  84% {
    width: 55px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 35px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 47px;
    right: 8px;
    top: 38px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateSuccessTip {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 19px;
  }
  54% {
    width: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 19px;
  }
  70% {
    width: 50px;
    left: -8px;
    top: 37px;
  }
  84% {
    width: 17px;
    left: 21px;
    top: 48px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 25px;
    left: 14px;
    top: 45px;
  }
}
@keyframes animateSuccessTip {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 19px;
  }
  54% {
    width: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 19px;
  }
  70% {
    width: 50px;
    left: -8px;
    top: 37px;
  }
  84% {
    width: 17px;
    left: 21px;
    top: 48px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 25px;
    left: 14px;
    top: 45px;
  }
}

@keyframes animateSuccessLong {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    right: 46px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  65% {
    width: 0;
    right: 46px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  84% {
    width: 55px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 35px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 47px;
    right: 8px;
    top: 38px;
  }
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line.sa-tip {
  width: 25px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 46px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line.sa-long {
  width: 47px;
  right: 8px;
  top: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotatePlaceholder {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  5% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotatePlaceholder {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  5% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg);
  }
}

</style>

<script>
/**
 * Source: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/
 */

$("button").click(function() {
  $(".sa-success").addClass("hide");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".sa-success").removeClass("hide");
  }, 10);
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="check_mark">
  <div class="sa-icon sa-success animate">
    <span class="sa-line sa-tip animateSuccessTip"></span>
    <span class="sa-line sa-long animateSuccessLong"></span>
    <div class="sa-placeholder"></div>
    <div class="sa-fix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<center>
  <button id="restart">Restart Animation</button>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

PD: Agradezco infinitamente por favor indicarme cuales son las lineas que debo modificar.

Comment: aumentar sería que se ejecute más rápido?

Comment: Disculpa aumentar el tamaño de toda la animación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés usar la propiedad [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform) de CSS en el elemento `.sa-icon`:

```
.sa-icon {
    ....
    transform: scale(2);
    /*Su uso requiere establecer las propiedades con sus prefijos
    para permitir la compatibilidad con todos los navegadores*/
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
check
</title>
<style type=text/css>
.check_mark {
  width: 80px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}

.sa-icon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transform: scale(2);
}

.sa-icon.sa-success {
  border-color: #4CAF50;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success::before, .sa-icon.sa-success::after {
  content: '';
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.sa-icon.sa-success::before {
  -webkit-border-radius: 120px 0 0 120px;
  border-radius: 120px 0 0 120px;
  top: -7px;
  left: -33px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 60px 60px;
  transform-origin: 60px 60px;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success::after {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 120px 120px 0;
  border-radius: 0 120px 120px 0;
  top: -11px;
  left: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 60px;
  transform-origin: 0px 60px;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-placeholder {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid rgba(76, 175, 80, .5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: -4px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-fix {
  width: 5px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 28px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.sa-icon.sa-success.animate::after {
  -webkit-animation: rotatePlaceholder 4.25s ease-in;
  animation: rotatePlaceholder 4.25s ease-in;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success {
  border-color: transparent\9;
}
.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line.sa-tip {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) \9;
}
.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line.sa-long {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) \9;
}

.animateSuccessTip {
  -webkit-animation: animateSuccessTip 0.75s;
  animation: animateSuccessTip 0.75s;
}

.animateSuccessLong {
  -webkit-animation: animateSuccessLong 0.75s;
  animation: animateSuccessLong 0.75s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateSuccessLong {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    right: 46px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  65% {
    width: 0;
    right: 46px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  84% {
    width: 55px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 35px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 47px;
    right: 8px;
    top: 38px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateSuccessTip {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 19px;
  }
  54% {
    width: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 19px;
  }
  70% {
    width: 50px;
    left: -8px;
    top: 37px;
  }
  84% {
    width: 17px;
    left: 21px;
    top: 48px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 25px;
    left: 14px;
    top: 45px;
  }
}
@keyframes animateSuccessTip {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 19px;
  }
  54% {
    width: 0;
    left: 1px;
    top: 19px;
  }
  70% {
    width: 50px;
    left: -8px;
    top: 37px;
  }
  84% {
    width: 17px;
    left: 21px;
    top: 48px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 25px;
    left: 14px;
    top: 45px;
  }
}

@keyframes animateSuccessLong {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    right: 46px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  65% {
    width: 0;
    right: 46px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  84% {
    width: 55px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 35px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 47px;
    right: 8px;
    top: 38px;
  }
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line.sa-tip {
  width: 25px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 46px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.sa-icon.sa-success .sa-line.sa-long {
  width: 47px;
  right: 8px;
  top: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotatePlaceholder {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  5% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotatePlaceholder {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  5% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg);
  }
}

</style>

<script>
/**
 * Source: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/
 */

$("button").click(function() {
  $(".sa-success").addClass("hide");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".sa-success").removeClass("hide");
  }, 10);
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="check_mark">
  <div class="sa-icon sa-success animate">
    <span class="sa-line sa-tip animateSuccessTip"></span>
    <span class="sa-line sa-long animateSuccessLong"></span>
    <div class="sa-placeholder"></div>
    <div class="sa-fix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<center>
  <button id="restart">Restart Animation</button>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Listo, justamente lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias.